# take a picture with android ndk - camera api

Tags: android, camera, android-ndk, android-camera

Is there a standarized API for taking pictures using Android NDK?

Or is it really necessary to go through Java for that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. It is necessary to go through Java. Since NDK access will be specific to particular hardware.

Inspite there are few realizations through NDK.

Check the following links for relevant details.

http://nhenze.net/?p=253

http://osdir.com/ml/android-ndk/2010-10/msg00518.html

Comment: +1 for links, but the claim "Since NDK access will be specific to particular hardware" is pure nonsense, or you think code that handles different hardware is written in Java? I'm pretty sure Java just calls some messy c-api that does all the dirty work.

Comment: the links are dead now.

Comment: This answer is obsolete since Android 7.

Answer (score 11):

In **Android 7** (API 24) Google has added support for native camera access (Camera2 API).

In ndk-r12:

- Headers:

  1. `$NDK_ROOT/android-24/$ARCH/usr/include/camera/Ndk*.h`
  2. `$NDK_ROOT/android-24/$ARCH/usr/include/media/Image*.h`
- Libs:

  1. `libcamera2ndk.so`
  2. `libmediandk.so`

Answer (score 5):

1) There was an access to `Camera.h` in older releases like [Froyo, 2.3.3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/include/camera/Camera.h).

Now, I see a `Camera.h` in [KitKat, 4.4.4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/kitkat-release/include/camera/Camera.h). It changed completely.

This is an unofficial API, so it's subject to change. Be ready to code and deploy different versions for different Android releases.

2) There is a `Camera` component in OpenMAX. People managed to create an [OpenMAX recorder for Raspbery Pi](https://github.com/gagle/raspberrypi-openmax-jpeg/blob/master/jpeg.c). I yet have to find a working solution for Android.

These two questions are unanswered:

- [OpenMAX recorder on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273898/openmax-recorder-on-android)
- [Access camera via OpenMAX in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930852/access-camera-via-openmax-in-android)

and I'm going to try OpenMAX.

3) We ran into an Android device where video4linux2 works (one can access `/dev/video0`).

Answer (score 1):

Post Android 7 or API version 24 : `Camera 2` APIs are possible not just in Java space but in the `native(NDK/C++`) space too. This [article](https://www.sisik.eu/blog/android/ndk/camera) give you all the details with code.