# How to use android ndk to access camera

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-camera

Does android-NDK support direct camera access? There is no Camera.h in my NDK folder.

Comment: AFAIK, camera access is only from Java.

Comment: You should be able to call the Java methods from native code though, right?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably going to need some kind of [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) action... Here is an SO Post that seems to address it: [take a picture with android ndk - camera api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297577/take-a-picture-with-android-ndk-camera-api)