# Android 6 Native Camera

Tags: android, c++, opencv, camera, native

So I'm trying to work on pure native android application as i need the performance of C/C++. I want to access the camera in a NativeActivity, grab the frames and process them using OpenCV and custom library. I have found multiple answers for using the new JavaCameraView with the cvCameraViewListener2 but in my opinion doing a JNI call to C++ everytime is completely unnecessary and time consuming - and a lot of the forums even post that JNI are expensive!

So my question is if there is either a way to integrate OpenCV in Android SDK Version 23 (6.0 Marshmellow) or another way of accessing the camera natively as i did not have any success finding an alternative. I am running android 6.0.1 on a Samsung Galaxy S7.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

so incase anyone was wondering how i solved it...upgrade to Android 7 was necessary. Android 7 introduced NdkCamera headers as [@y30](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5052296/y30) has answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39458736/3344164).